# Netbeans 8.0 wrongly gives "Unknown HTML tag" warning

Tags: java, html, netbeans, javadoc

When using the elements `kbd` or `samp` in JavaDoc comments for Java 7 source code, Netbeans 8.0 flags these elements with a warning such as `Unknown HTML Tag: <kbd>`.

These elements are valid in HTML 4.1 (which is the format produced by the JavaDoc generator) and in the newer HTML5 specification, so Netbeans seems incorrect to declare them unknown.

Is there a way I can edit the list of HTML elements recognised by Netbeans 8.0?

(I am aware that this type of warning can be disabled in Netbeans, but I don't want to do this. I want to receive warnings about genuinely invalid markup, but in this case the markup is valid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug of netbeans 8.0. Someone as already filled a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243900) for the elements `<s>` and `<strike>`. You can sign in to the netbeans bugzilla database and complete the bug report. Then you just have to wait and hope that it will be fixed in the next release.

The other possibility is to patch NetBeans but it could be a little bit difficult.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem here isn't Netbeans itself, because it recognizes these Tags just fine when they are used in any .html (.phtml, .jsp, ...) file.

I think that these tags may not be supported by JavaDoc or the parser that generates the JavaDoc at the end and therefore Netbeans tells you that these aren't valid HTML Tags.

But I'm not sure about this, it is just a guess, because as mentioned the tags are recognized in .html files.